# Why does Source Safe 2005 display all project folders in Project Differences?

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

From within Visual SourceSafe 2005 I'm selecting 
**Show Differences** 
**Show files that are different in both locations** and **Recursive**

There are no differences between the files in SourceSafe and the files in Working Directory however . . .

After Visual SourceSafe 2005 completes the comparison the (Project Difference) dialog shows every (Folder) in the project, to me, suggesting there are many differences.

Does anyone know why Visual SourceSafe 2005 lists all project folders in Project Differences even though there are no differences?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SourceSafe on the screenshot shows that there are actually 0 differences. I guess that there should be an option to hide non-modified items in the [Project Difference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/7110w6z4%28v%3Dvs.80%29) dialog.

Note that the modified items would be marked with blue. Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Apparently the Project Difference dialog will not only display file differences but will always display each folder in your project even when there are absolutely no file differences